# cross compile git repository with mingw under Ubuntu

Tags: c, eclipse, cross-compiling, mingw32, mingw-w64

I have a git repository which I can build with:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now I want to cross compile it for windows with the mingw32/mingw-w64 cross compiler.

I tried it with

```
export CXX=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

but that didn't work for me.

I have configure eclipse that I can compile windows executables as well, that works, but only with plane c code. Now I need external libraries, which I have to compile for windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on a(n old, but mostly correct) [page of the MinGW-w64 wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/MSYS/) (written by yours truly a long time ago):

./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32

should do the trick if the package doesn't need special handling for Windows.